# Extract strings with exactly only two dots

Tags: unix

I am looking to extract strings that have exactly 2 dots like below.

```
a.b.c

$$abc.$$def.123
```

The relevance is only to the dots.

So far i have tried

```
grep "\\.{2}" file_name.txt.
```

But this is not giving me the result. Could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a regular expression issue. Your \.{2} will match two *consecutive* dots. What you'll probably want is something like:

```
^[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$
```

Which is "start of string, zero or more not-dots, a dot, zero or more not-dots, a dot, zero or more not-dots, end of string".

Comment: Thank you for the quick response !! However I had tried this and its even returning strings without dots. Strings like 'abcdefjjk'.

Comment: I'm sorry could you provide a sample of the file you're using? It appears to be working for the few tests I've tried. It should be matching lines that contain two dots.

Comment: I am really sorry ZJM. It is indeed working. Just a typo in my test run.